# Divide Crystal Report Vertically in Two Parts

Tags: c#, crystal-reports, crystal-reports-2010

I have to SP, from which i want to generate Report. I need output in two different Columns on one Detail Sections. I have tried `Format with Multiple Columns`, but it do not full fill my needs..

```
-- My Data
-- Student Record
  +------+------------+
  | Name | FatherName |
  +------+------------+
  |  A   |   B        |
  |  C   |   D        |
  |  E   |   F        |
  +------+------------+

    --Teacher Record
  +------+------------+
  |Name  | FatherName |
  +------+------------+
  |  W   |   X        |
  |  Y   |   Z        |
  +------+------------+
```

My required out will look like below ...

```
 Students Record                             Teachers Record
+------+------------+                    +------+------------+
| Name | FatherName |                    | Name | FatherName |
+------+------------+                    +------+------------+
| A    |     B      |                    |   W  |      X     |
| C    |     D      |                    |   Y  |      Z     |
| E    |     F      |                    +------+------------+
+------+------------+
```

Is there any way to get this output in one Detail Section. Student and Teacher have different number of records, one have 10 record 2nd have 5 record..

Any Help...

Comment: How is the 'My Data' data logically related to students and teachers?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't do this in one detail section in Crystal Reports.

However, you can develop a report for each of these tables separately, then add the two reports side-by-side as sub-reports into a new report - this should achieve your objective.

Comment: You means inside one report, i will have to add to Sub-reports, one for each SP.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can do it by right-clicking the details section then Insert->subreport, one for Teachers record and one for the Students record, then editing these subreports with their respective data source.

Comment: -1 The subreports will be repeated for every record in the main report, if they are placed in the details section.

Comment: You can probably do this using the same SP to populate a subreport.  You can duplicate the subreport and place the two side-by-side.  Use the built in Xtal record selection to limit one subreport to the Student Record records and limit the other to the Teacher Record records.  One report, added twice, with record selection controls added to the sub-report.